# .Net Core - How to add SQL Column Constraint using EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In a .net core 3.1 web application, what file am I suppose to edit to add a DEFAULT constraint to a table that is being created by EF?

Right now I have a migrations folder with a InitialCreate, RenamedTable, and TableDefault migration.  Before creating the TableDefault migration, I went into the DbContextModelSnapshot.cs file and added this to one of the columns

```
b.Property<string>("EmergencyChange")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)")
                        .HasDefaultValue("False"); //Default constraint I added
```

I then created a new migration and gave it the name TableDefault.  However, when I go to update-database, I notice the down method is actually applying those constraints and not the UP method?

```
public partial class TableDefaults : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "Submitter",
                table: "tblChanges",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(string),
                oldType: "nvarchar(max)",
                oldDefaultValueSql: "SUSER_Name()");

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "EmergencyChange",
                table: "tblChanges",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(string),
                oldType: "nvarchar(max)",
                oldDefaultValue: "False");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "Submitter",
                table: "tblChanges",
                type: "nvarchar(max)",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValueSql: "SUSER_Name()",
                oldClrType: typeof(string));

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "EmergencyChange",
                table: "tblChanges",
                type: "nvarchar(max)",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: "False",
                oldClrType: typeof(string));
        }
    }
```

So when I run the UP method, it basically does nothing, but if I revert back to the 2nd migration, it runs the down method and now all of a sudden the constraint is applied.  So, what am I doing wrong?  I could just swap the UP/DOWN method, but I am pretty certain I am doing something fundamentally incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*Snapshot.cs` is not meant to be modified. At the top of the file we have this :

```
// <auto-generated />
```

It is always auto-generated and updated by EF Core when you add a new migration file.

Your default constraint should be added on your migration file instead. You just need to put it into the `Up` method. You already have there `defaultValueSql` or `defaultValue` for that kind of thing. Don't modify the `*Snapshot.cs` file.

Comment: To clarify, I should have created a blank migration and then simply wrote the code by hand?  I would also have to write the down method otherwise I wouldn't be able to revert to a previous migration?

Comment: @DylanJanszen If the default value is the only one thing to modify on your model then you should have created a blank migration and then add the modification there. Yep for a blank migration, the `Down` method need to be implemented also to revert in case what was done in `Up`method.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to add Constraints on Modelbuilder

```html
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .Property(b => b.Created)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
}
```

Comment: In the snapshot.cs file?  Which file location are you referring to?  I am pretty sure that is incorrect if that is what you mean.

Comment: In your DbContext or  using seprate class which is derived from IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>

Comment: Why not have it as its' own migration?

Answer (score 0):

You could, As it is entity configuration rather than migration, all your entity configuration are in one place